# Macro Find: Is there a macro to Format a Word Document as if it were being created in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a lots of code (for Excel) in VBA and would like to transfer a copy of it into a Word document.

Does anyone know of a macro that will format the Word document to treat the code as if it were in VBA?

So things like, "For" "And" "Or" "Then" would be changed to Blue
and the font would be the same.

I'm not really looking to actually code in Word but make a "look-a-like"
I have no experience with VBA in Word so I can't write myself (otherwise I would, of course checking first to make sure that there isn't one readily available I can use.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found a Word plugin that can handle **VBScript highlightning** here : http://www.regexlab.com/sswater/en/wordsyntax/index.htm (maybe you could adapt it for VBA specific syntax if you can access the code).

By the way, seems like MZTools can handle it on the **VBEditor**, maybe you could get the code to use it *inside* a Word document : http://www.mztools.com/v3/features.as

Comment: You answered the question + a question I didn't even ask!! Thanks Alot!!